# Efficiently remove duplicates and similar elements from a list

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have a List which contains equal-length-sequences (In this example the length of the sequences is 2, but it can be longer than that in other cases) of numbers, for example:

```
[[3, 2], [0, 6], [6, 0], [7, 7], [0, 5], [7, 7]]
```

Now I want to remove all duplicates (`[7, 7]` appears twice) but also remove all reverse duplicates (`[0, 6]` and `[6, 0]`).

My current code is this:

```py
def getUniqueShapes(shapes):
    unique = []
    for shape in shapes:
        if shape not in unique and reversed(shape) not in unique:
            shapes.append(shape)

    print(unique)
```

My expected output for this example is

```py
[[3, 2], [0, 6], [7, 7], [0, 5]]
```

Because of the `not in`, this algorithm runs with very poor speed.
Is there an easy way I can apply such a condition to the list with a better time complexity?

Comment: Have you considered using sets?

Comment: you also don't append to unique in this code

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not sure if sets would work since I don't only want to check if list elements are equal, but also if the reversed element is equal to another one.

Comment: What do you mean by remove? Remove both of them or just on of them. If one of them which one?

Comment: `{1, 2} == {2, 1}`...

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, for this case it would work, but once the length exceeds 2, the order cannot be preserved... (`[1, 2, 3] =! [2, 1, 3]`)

Comment: That constraint is not in your question

Comment: what's your sample output?

Comment: @C.Nivs I didn't have an output because the code ran forever because I wasn't appending to `unique` as @GoingTharn pointed out.

Comment: I mean your intended result

Comment: @C.Nivs For this example `[[3, 2], [0, 6], [7, 7], [0, 5]]` or `[[3, 2], [6, 0], [7, 7], [0, 5]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Assuming in case of `[1, 0]`, `[0, 1]` both means same.
- You need to convert lists to tuple first because `list` is not hashable.
- Also output is set of tuples you can easily convert it to list of lists.

```
>>> l = [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 4], [5, 6], [5, 6]]
>>> set(map(tuple, map(sorted, l)))
{(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)}
```

Edit: This will work for any length cases elements.